# NodeJS: Unhandled promise rejection

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, promise, es6-promise

I'm having a little problem and after debugged all the app I noticed that this is the file that's causing the problem, returning me a `UnhandledPromiseRejection`

```
'use strict'

const connection = require('../models/'),
      oracledb   = require('oracledb'),
      conexion   = oracledb.getConnection(connection)
oracledb.outFormat = oracledb.OBJECT;

module.exports  = {
  index(req, res) {
  conexion.then(con => {
    return con.execute(
      `SELECT id_application, name, description, creation_date ` +
      `FROM application `
    ).then(bucket => {
      return con.execute(
        `SELECT id_definition, id_application, field_name_original, field_name_new,
        column_name, position, id_type_data, field_size, creation_date,
        description, filter, visible ` +
        `FROM definition `
      ).then(definitions => {
        res.status(200).json(creaJSON(bucket, definitions))
      }).catch(error  => { return res.status(500).json({'message': error}) })
    }).catch(err  =>  { return res.status(500).json({'message': err}) })
  }).catch(err  =>  { return res.status(500).json({'message': err}) })
  },
  create(req, res)  {
  },
  update(req, res)  {
  }
}

const doRelease = (connection) => {
  connection.close((err)  =>  {
    if(err) console.error(err.message);
  })
}

const creaJSON = (buckets, definitions)  => {
  var df = new Array()
  buckets['rows'].map(obj =>  {
    definitions['rows'].map(def =>  {
      if(obj['ID_APPLICATION'] == def['ID_APPLICATION']) df.push(def)
    })
    obj['Definitions'] = df
    df = []
  })
  return buckets.rows
}
```

after the `UnhandledPromiseRejection` is being followed by: `Error: ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred`

```
(node:1270) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.JS process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I already looked for solutions, some says that promises are not catching correctly but I don't see any problem with them. Any other suggestion?

Any help will be welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const connection = require('../models/'),
  oracledb   = require('oracledb'),
  conexion   = oracledb.getConnection(connection)
```

is setting `conexion` to the promise returned by a call to `.getConnection` made when the entire source file is executed (in response to being required).

`conexion` has no handlers at this point. Handlers are only added later when the `index`method of the exported `{index, create, update}` object is called.

Hence connection timeout  in between the source file being required and `index` being called will produce an unhandled rejection error.

Obviously adding a catch clause such as

```
 conexion   = oracledb.getConnection(connection).catch( onRejected)
```

should fix this error, but how much recovery you want to put into coding `onRejected` is up to you.

---

Edit:

A less obvious approach to satisfying V8's version of how to handle uncaught promise rejection is to provide a dummy handler to thwart it:

```
conexion   = oracledb.getConnection(connection);
conexion.catch(()=>undefined); // a do nothing catch handler.
```

Here the second line adds a handler to the `conexion` promise, making it "handled", which prevents it ever becoming an uncaught promise rejection. The promise returned by `catch` is superfluous and not recorded, but will be *fulfilled* if the no-operation catch handler is ever called.

Now the promise held in *conexion* can be rejected before `index` is called without generating an exception. Whether this is the best way to code promise topology for a particular application is a different question - you may very well wish to address a connection timeout earlier.

Comment: Nice, I can't try it right now because I'm not at job but Monday will check it up. Thank you so much. @Traktor53

Comment: Nice, thank you, the ```UnhandledPromiseRejection``` is gone, now I just have ```Error: ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred``` hahahaha. I'll checkout if I can fix this, if not I'll open another question. Thank you sir.